# Normalization of standard deviation

Tags: standard-deviation, variance

I have a question regarding standard deviation. Let me start with an example: I have response times (RT) from users, let's say

```
RT1 = 3s
RT2 = 5s
RT3 = 8s
```

I have a normalizing constant for the response time (what the response time usually should be). Let's say this constant is 4s. So we have the normalized response times:

```
RT1 = 3s / 4
RT2 = 5s / 4
RT3 = 8s / 4
```

Now I would like to calculate the standard deviation. For the standard deviation I also have a constant indicating what the standard deviation typically is.

Should I now use the normalized response times or the original response times to calculate the standard deviation and then dividing by the normalization constant for the standard deviation?

Comment: Have you calculated the two different standard deviations you're talking about? Is one twice as big as the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard deviation scales under multiplication by a constant:
if $X$ has standard deviation $\sigma$, then $cX$ has standard deviation $|c| \sigma$.  So it doesn't matter whether you first calculate the standard deviation and then normalize, or first normalize and then calculate the standard deviation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to normalize the standard deviation either way. The difference is the usage of normalized or non normalized response times for the calculation.